Change the content of a powerpoint using MS add-ins
I am trying to open a presentation in MS- PowerPoint. I have created a add-In for it. It has a button which will retrieve the file on click of a button from s3 and then it will upload the file into the singed In users' OneDrive.
I am able to achieve it using Microsoft Graph API and S3 API in the backend.
However I cannot replace the file which is currently open in the PowerPoint, the graph API give me 423 error as I cannot modify a file which is already open.
async function uploadToOneDrive(fileBlob, fileName, accessToken) {
    const uploadUrl = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Documents/${fileName}:/content`;

    try {
        const response = await fetch(uploadUrl, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
            },
            body: fileBlob
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Error uploading file to OneDrive: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Upload to OneDrive failed:', error);
    }
}

I am using Graph API to upload the file and using MSAL libraries since I have used it before. This API will not work and will give me (423 error) .Is there any other way to achieve this?
Can I use Office JavaScript API?
If yes how can I parse the content from the blob file I got from S3?
How complex would it be?
Thanks in Advance

I found out the Office JavaScript API insertSlidesFromBase64(base64format) method to change the content of the current PowerPoint and not using Graph API.
I just have to remove all the existing content first and then add the content at the end of the file.
By doing this I can easily get the base 64 format of the file from my exiting backend code.
Sample Code -
PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
const base64String = "your_base64_encoded_pptx_string_here";
context.presentation.insertSlidesFromBase64(base64String);
await context.sync();
    console.log("Slides inserted from Base64!");
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

And I can delete the earlier content using the delete capabilities of the API
sample code for delete -
PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
                const slides = context.presentation.slides;
                slides.load("items");
                await context.sync();

                // Delete all slides
                slides.items.forEach(slide => slide.delete());
                await context.sync();

                console.log("All slides deleted");
            });

Using these two features I can change the content of the current PowerPoint presentation from a different file via MS-Office Add In task pane.

If your


} catch (error) {
        console.error('Upload to OneDrive failed:', error);



does not actiavate, check your code using a PowerShell script.


Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Path\To\YourExecutable.exe" -ArgumentList "arg1", "arg2"
-- With parameters using JS   


-- Using norm Powershell opening

.\YourExecutable.exe
-- Paths
C:/Path/Path/Path/File




Hi, my error does activate, the issue is I am not able to replace the presentation which is currently opened using graph API.
I don't want that error and I want the content to be updated despite it being opened .
